# How can an app handle intents without having any intent-filters in its manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

My understanding is that, in order to handle external intents, an app's `manifest.xml` file must contain an `intent-filter`; however, using APK Analyzer, I saw that the manifest of the Spotify app is merely:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><manifest versionCode="55843262" configForSplit="" package="com.spotify.music" split="config.xxhdpi">
  <application hasCode="false">
    <meta-data name="com.android.vending.derived.apk.id" value="8"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

This shows no intent filters; however, I am able to open Spotify with:

```
adb shell am start -a "android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" -e android.intent.extra.focus "vnd.android.cursor.item/*" -e query Bowie
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

That manifest indicates the APK contains no code:

```
<application hasCode="false">
```

Either there is another APK with the code in it (which will also contain the rest of the manifest entries you are missing), or Spotify is using Google Play Dynamic Delivery which allows modules to be downloaded and installed on the fly.

In any case, you aren't looking at the whole manifest for the app.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I'd find the other APK (if it exists)? The 3rd-party app APK Analyzer doesn't list it.

Comment: No, sorry. I don't.